# Changing the main image in a gallery slider by clicking on a separate link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to change the main image inside a gallery slider using separate thumbnail links with HTML5 and JavaScript.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <script src="slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <title>Gallery Slider</title>
        </head>
                <body>
                  </article>

                    <div id="container">
                     <img src="Fimages/img1.png" name="slideshow" id="img"/>
                          <div id="left_holder">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img onClick=" slide(-1)" class="left" src="Fimages/arrow_left.png"/></a>
                          </div>
                          <div id="right_holder"> 
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img onClick="slide(1)" class="right" src="Fimages/arrow_right.png"/></a>
                          </div>
                     </div>

                    <div id="description"></div>


                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(?)">pic 1</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(?)">pic 2</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(?)">pic 3</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(?)">pic 4</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(?)">pic 5</a>

                <article> 
            </body>
    </html>
```

I have the JavaScript slider working correctly when I slide back and forth but I can't change the main image inside "container" div or the "description" div when I click on separate thumbnail links. 
Do I need to create another function? If possible could I please have the explanation in JavaScript since I'm trying to learn more about it. Please find my JavaScript below.

```
   var Image = ["Fimages/img1.png", "Fimages/img2.png","Fimages/img3.png","Fimages/img4.png","Fimages/img5.png"];
   var Description = ["1.description...", "2. description...", "3. description...", "4. description...", "5.description..."];
   var Image_Number = 0;
   var Image_Length = Image.length -1;


   function slide(num){
    Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

     if (Image_Number > Image_Length){
        Image_Number = 0;       
     }

     if (Image_Number < 0){
        Image_Number = Image_Length;
     }

     document.slideshow.src=Image[Image_Number];
     document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = Description[Image_Number];
     return false;
     }

   //Do I need another function to call up an Image and a Description?
    function thumbnail(x){

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change the source of your image with `img` id

```
document.getElementById("img").src="ImageSourceHere.png";
```

to change the content of your div with id `description`

```
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = "your description here";
```

refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) for documentation of `inenrHtml`

refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) for documentation of `getElementById`

for your specific case

```
function thumbnail(x){
    Image_Number = x;
    document.slideshow.src=Image[Image_Number];
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = Description[Image_Number];
}
```

this function needs a check to know `if x is >= 0 and x < ImageLength`

Comment: That works but is there a way of calling it from the 'Image' and 'Description' arrays I've already created so that I can just give a value to (x)? for example onClick="thumbnail(x).

Comment: do you want something like this `document.getElementById("img").src=Image[x];` where `x` is the index that you want to display?

Comment: I've updeted my answer. Let me know if works for you.

Comment: Yes that would be good then I only need to add an index number to call both 'Image' and 'Description'

Comment: did you see my updated answer? I have wrote a function to do that

Comment: I tried your code and I couldn't index the last image or description in either arrays. You led me in the right direction and I did find some code that works.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm only new to JavaScript but the one I left above (below your answer) seems to work.

Comment: I've left the code that works for you. Hope it solve your question